# ¿Como sacar el valor maximo en una tabla en MySql?

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin, select

Necesito como sacar el listado de las marcas (brand) con el producto más caro que tenga la marca. En clase estamos empezando a dar las querys y los inner join no los hemos dado, pero tenemos que sacarlo de esta forma. Buscando en Internet he conseguido llegar a esta conclusión, el problema es que no se como arreglar el problema que me aparece.

```
SELECT `brand`, MAX(`price`)
FROM `products` p
INNER JOIN `products` b ON b.prod_id = p.prod_id
GROUP BY `brand`
ORDER BY `brand`;
```

El problema es que me pone que el campo brand es ambiguo, y no se como resolverlo. Se que es que sql no reconoce de que brand estoy hablando.
Agradecería mucho que me echaseis una mano.
Gracias de antemano <3.

Comment: Ese JOIN te sobra, estás añadiendo una referencia a la misma tabla y hace que tengas dos columnas price.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Te pone que el campo `brand` es ambiguo porque en tu consulta hay más de una referencia de tabla que tiene una columna llamanda `brand`, entonces el SGBD se pregunta *¿de cuál de las columnas `brand` estás hablando?*

Para evitar eso, tienes que poner delante de la columna el nombre de la tabla o de su alias, si estás usando alias, como en este caso.

Por ejemplo:

```
SELECT 
    p.`brand`, 
    MAX(p.`price`) AS max_price
FROM `products` AS p
INNER JOIN `products` AS b ON b.`prod_id` = p.`prod_id`
GROUP BY p.`brand`
ORDER BY p.`brand`;
```

Si observas, yo puse el alias `p` donde quiera que aparecía `brand`. Con eso le digo al SGBD que quiero la columna `brand` de la tabla cuyo alias es `p` en la consulta. Aunque el error de ambigüedad sólo ocurre cuando a las tablas hay columnas con el mismo nombre, conviene que siempre que haya varias tablas en tus consultas, pongas delante de cada columna el alias de su respectiva tabla. Así la consulta es más clara (sabes en todo momento a qué tabla pertenece cada columna) y evitas el problema de la ambigüedad cuando éste pueda darse.

De todos modos, tu consulta no tiene mucho sentido, porque unes a la tabla consigo misma en la misma columna. Esta consulta haría lo mismo:

```
SELECT 
    `brand`, 
    MAX(`price`) AS max_price
FROM `products`;
```

Pero lo dicho más arriba vale en una consulta que realmente necesite más de una tabla.

Consideremos un ejemplo en el que tienes una tabla `emisor_receptor` que guarda mensajes enviados entre persona. Esa tabla guarda en una columna `emisor_id` el ID de la persona que manda el mensaje, y en una columna `receptor_id` el ID de la persona que lo recibe, y tiene una columna `mensaje` con el texto del mensaje.

La tabla se vería así más o menos:

```
emisor_id       receptor_id     mensaje
------------------------------------------------
    1                2          Hola ¿qué hay?
    2                1          Todo bien, ¿y tú?
```

Esta consulta tendría que hacer un doble JOIN de la tabla persona. Si tú no pones el alias de la tabla para cada cosa, pronto estarás perdido en una consulta más o menos compleja:

```
SELECT 
    e.`persona_nom` AS emisor,
    r.`persona_nom` AS receptor,
    er.`mensaje`
FROM `emisor_receptor` AS er
    INNER JOIN `persona` AS e
        ON er.`emisor_id`=e.`persona_id`;
    INNER JOIN `persona` AS r
        ON er.`receptor_id`=r.`persona_id`;
```

Aquí, las columnas `persona_nom` y `persona_id` se repiten varias veces en la consulta, pero no hay problema, porque delante de ellas se está poniendo en cada caso la referencia de la tabla. Y, en el caso de columnas que no se repiten, también se pone el alias de la tabla delante, lo cual arroja claridad en la consulta.

Comment: Muchas gracias, tu respuesta me ha sido de gran ayuda. ¡Un saludo!