# Como Evitar Ambigüedad En Mysql?

Tags: mysql, sql

El problema que tengo es que estoy haciendo una consulta y me sale el error de ambigüedad.

He intentado poner delante de " Codigocliente " un caracter, pero me sale el error de que la tabla no existe.

Adjunto fotos:

El Ejercicio-->
Devuelve un listado que muestre los empleados que no tienen una oficina asociada o que no tienen un cliente asociado.

y así lo estoy intentando hacer...[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
Select Nombre, CodigoEmpleado 
from Empleados e left join Oficinas o on
e.CodigoOficina = o.CodigoOficina 
where CodigoOficina is null;
```

Comment: Pon los e y o para todos los valores. Ambiguedad significa, que no estas especifica con los valores, que das algunas con una e o o y algunas sin decir donde pertenecen.

Comment: Y deberia ser un right join si queiras algo sin conecciones.

Comment: He añadido la sintaxis de la seguiente forma:    Select Nombre, e.CodigoEmpleado from
Empleados e right join 
Oficinas o on
e.CodigoOficina=o.CodigoOficina where e.CodigoOficina  is null;         -----pero no me carga nada, me sale el error de 0 rows returned

Comment: Aqui con right join, quita el is null parte....

Comment: Solamente: Select Nombre, e.CodigoEmpleado from Empleados e right join Oficinas o on e.CodigoOficina=o.CodigoOficina

Comment: Pon right join sql en un search Google

Comment: A ver, left join y codioficina=null esta correcto. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2686254/how-to-select-all-records-from-one-table-that-do-not-exist-in-another-table

Comment: Mi opcion percepción de right join fue mal.

Comment: A ver, mejor version en mi respuesta. Lo siento de todo right join....

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Si codigodeoficiona esta en las dos tablas (y por mas que sepamos que es el mismo), cual queres que muestre en tu consulta? eso es ambiguedad... la db te dice que no sabe de donde sacar esa columna.... Lee los enlaces... aprende a usar el sitio...

Comment: Hay una práctica muy simple y además saludable para evitar la ambigüedad: **cuando uses más de una tabla en la consulta, pon el nombre o alias de la tabla delante de cada columna**, la ventaja es doble: no tendrás problemas de ambigüedad y tu código quedará más claro, pues sabrás en cada caso a qué tabla refiere cada columna. Revisa [esta respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/511152/29967) para más detalles.

Comment: Muchas gracias!

Comment: Gracias!! un saludo

Answer (score 0):

Sin tomar más en cuenta toda la consulta de SQL, ambigüedad significa en SQL lo siguiente:

Mismo valor puede ocurrir en varias tablas en bases de datos. Si no estás especificando cuál de los valores estás usando, viene el error.

En tu ejemplo, tienes Nombre y CodigoEmpleado, pero en los otras valores tú tienes con un e o o, diciendo de dónde son. Utiliza lo mismo para Nombre y CodigoEmpleado también.

Tu código está en buen camino:

No tengo tu base de datos, pero sería este más cerquita:

```
Select Nombre
from Empleados e left join Oficinas o on
e.CodigoOficina = o.CodigoOficina 
where e.CodigoOficina is null and not exists(
    SELECT 1 FROM Clientes c 
    where c.CodigoEmpleadoRepVentas = e.CodigoEmpleado
);
```

Mira más acerca de cómo los dos métodos usados en el código funcionan:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2686254/how-to-select-all-records-from-one-table-that-do-not-exist-in-another-table (inglés)

Comment: Mil gracias por tu apoyo ! un saludo. El Join me trae loco :/

Comment: Ya encontre una solución con el join, también...